# I can't validate an email field

Tags: java, android

I'm currently doing a project in which contains a registration form and the email validation must contain a "libraryparadise.com" or "gmail.com" after the '@' symbol which I can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: Just search for `email validadtion`. You'll find a bunch of regex for that putpose. Adapt the code for Android. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code to check email validation 
 Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher just check proper email pattern Like "abc@xyz.com"

```
  String email=emailText.getText().toString();
         //check email patterns validation
          if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Email not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return;
          }else{
               Toast.makeText(context, "Email not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid creating regular expressions for the email validation, you can use next code

```
private void validateEmail() {
    String email = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    if (PatternsCompat.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches() &&
            (email.endsWith("@gmail.com") || email.endsWith("libraryparadise.com"))) {
        setEmail(email);
    } else {
        displayError();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a nice workaround, I tested it on normal emails and it works fine but emails like (.abc@xyz.com) , (abc.@xyz.com) and (abc@def.xyz.com) didn't succeed though.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a great solution to email validation given the complexities of email addresses.

Consider a two part validation
1. Validate that the email address text ends with "@libraryparadise.com" or "@gmail.com" and has 1 character to the left of the "@" character
2. Use a regular expression to validate the email address

It's easier to break these validations into multiple checks instead of one big regular expression.  A future developer can read the code to see the checks in order more easily if they are in different checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Regular Expressions**

If you are sure that you just want "libraryparadise.com" and "gmail.com", then you can use two regular expressions and compare them like this.

```
  String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@gmail.com*$";
  String regex2 = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0- 
  9_]+)*@libraryparadise.com*$";

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex2);
```

Get the view that contains the text

```
sampleText=findViewById(R.id.sampleText);
```

Then use this anywhere in a condition.

```
if(pattern.matcher(sampleText.getText().toString().trim()).matches()||
   pattern2.matcher(sampleText.getText().toString().trim()).matches()){

   //ValidEmail

}
else { 

     //Invalid Email

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much kind sir, ill try and inform you if it succeed!!